Let C be the path in $\Bbb R^2$ from from $(0,0)$ to $(2,1)$ defined by the equation $x^4-6xy^3-4y^2=0$. Find $\int_C (10x^4-2xy^3)dx -3x^2y^2dy.$
Let C be the path in $\Bbb R^2$ from from $(0,0)$ to $(2,1)$ defined by the equation $x^4-6xy^3-4y^2=0$. Find $\int_C (10x^4-2xy^3 ) dx -3x^2y^2dy$.
I have no idea how to do this line integral. In our Calculus-III course we are taught to solve line integrals of a function along a curve in case the parametric equation of the curve is given to us.
What I learnt was, if the parametric equation of a curve $C$ is $x=x(t), y=y(t)$ with $a\leq t\leq b$ then $$\int_C f(x,y)dx=\int_{a}^b f(x(t),y(t))x'(t)dt$$ and $$\int_C f(x,y)dy=\int_{a}^b f(x(t),y(t))y'(t)dt.$$
I also learnt that if $\vec F$ is a conservative vector field and $C$ is a curve with the parametric equation $\vec r(t)=x(t)\vec i+ \vec y(t)\vec j$ and $a\leq t\leq b$ then, $$\int_C\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\vec f(\vec r(b))-\vec f(\vec r(a)),$$ where $\nabla f=\vec F.$
But the given function is not a vector field and neither we are able to parameterise the curve so, I'm confused. Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

The curve can indeed be parameterized by $\left(x,y(x)\right)$ or $\left(x(y),y\right)$ so long as one carefully chooses the solution to the resp. cubic/quartic that corresponds to the part of the given curve. Unfortunately, this path leads to complicated expressions.

Your second idea is the right one (but I don't think your statement is correct):
You should recognise that a parametrisation of this curve (although probably not impossible) will be very difficult. Therefore, we should use the fundamental theorem of line integrals which says:
If F is a conservative vector field, i.e $\mathbf{F}=\nabla f$ for some scalar function $f$, then:
$$\int^b_a \mathbf{F}\cdot  d \mathbf{r}=f(\mathbf{r}(b))-f(\mathbf{r}(a))$$, with $f$ defined as above.
In this case , we should recognise that the vector field F is:
$\mathbf{F}=<10x^4-2xy^3,-3x^2y^2>$, and a suitable $f$ is $f(x,y,z)=2x^5-x^2y^3$. (You should verify this statement for clarity).
Then :
$\int^b_a \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{r}=f(2,1)-f(0,0)=2\times32-2^2\times 1^3-0=60$

On a side note, anybody know if that is the right way to write boldened vectors , only way I can think of really?

$\bf{v}$.......

@J.Dmaths I studied from Paul's Online Notes and it seems to be the one written like that for conservative vector fields.

@ThomasFinley I'll have a look, it may very well be a difference in the way we were taught it. You mind dropping a link?

@J.Dmaths Here is the link: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/FundThmLineIntegrals.aspx

@ThomasFinley It says the same formula as I stated above: Yours is not correct, as you use capital F, instead of lower case f (where $F=\nabla f)$. Think about it: does it make sense that the result of the integral would be a vector (as it does now if the RHS uses $\mathbf{F}$ instead of lower case f)

@J.D Thanks! I get it
